# vim problems under cygwin on Windows 7

Tags: vim, cygwin, win64

I cannot access vim or vi under the cygwin shell. The only available selection in the setup program under Editors is 'vim-minimal' which is allegedly installed (says 'Keep' beside it in the installer's tree view).

```
$ vim
/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/git/bin/vim: line 3: /share/vim/vim74/vim: No such file or directory
/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/git/bin/vim: line 3: exec: /share/vim/vim74/vim: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

I found this nice bit of magic to try:
http://simonmcc.blogspot.in/2005/06/cygwin-vim-rxvt-arrow-key-problems.html
...but got blocked because I cannot get to the dir where the vimrc file resides...

I can list the vim directory from my home dir:

```
$ pwd
/cygdrive/c/Users/Michael
$ ls -a /usr/share/vim
.
..
autoload
filetype.vim
ftoff.vim
menu.vim
optwin.vim
plugin
scripts.vim
syntax
tutor
vim.exe
```

...but when I try to go there...

```
$cd /usr/share/vim
bash: cd: /usr/share/vim: No such file or directory
```

...and trying to sneak up on it, I find...

```
$ cd /usr/share
$ ls -a
.
..
awk
bash-completion
doc
file
groff
info
locale
magic
man
misc
p11-kit
pki
tabset
terminfo
zoneinfo
zoneinfo-leaps
zoneinfo-posix
```

No 'vim' directory! Gak!

Comment: I gave an answer, but this question really belongs in http://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `vim-miminal` provides `vi`, package `vim` provides `vim`.  They are both there in my setup program.  Don't just look under 'Editors', try searching for 'vim' in the search box at the top of the setup program window.

Your setup program says you have vi, what happens when you type `vi` or `vi.exe` in the console?

I don't know what's going on with your /usr/share/vim directory, or why there's a vim.exe in your /usr/share directory, that's all really odd.  `vim.exe` should be in /usr/bin.  What happens when you do `which vi` or `which vim`?

The `cygcheck` program checks the status of Cygwin packages.  `cygcheck -c vim` should return with 'OK' if it's installed correctly, nothing if not at all, or 'Incomplete' if something is wrong.

Try grabbing a new [setup-x86_64.exe](https://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe) and running setup again, and/or choose another mirror.  There should be both a `vim` and a `vim-common` package (as well as `gvim` and `vim-latex`).

Comment: `$ which vi
/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/git/bin/vi`

Comment: `$ which vim
/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/git/bin/vim`

Comment: I loaded the exe from your link and the setup package still contains only 'vim-minimal' under the 'Base' tree node. I guess a complete uninstall is next.

Comment: Did you try a different mirror?

Comment: Yes, and that did help, @pak. Thanks. I just have to reset my definition of 'mirror' to mean 'a copy that may or may not be like the original.' :)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem on my system, and the fix was to change the Cygwin setup GUI's current view from 'Pending' to 'Full'.

This has caught me a few times, looking for various packages.  This time, when searching for 'vim', the GUI reported only 'vim-minimal', because:

1. The GUI view was set to 'Pending' by default,
2. An update WAS pending for 'vim-minimal' because my version was out-of-date, and
3. I hadn't already installed any other packages that had 'vim' in the name and that were also out-of-date.

(The choices for View are:  Full, Pending, Up To Date, Not Installed, Picked, and Category.)

I changed the view to 'Full', and it showed a lot more vim items, including the package named only 'vim'.

After installing vim, gvim, etc., nothing showed when searching for 'vim' in Pending view, because 'vim-minimal' was automatically upgraded, and no longer pending an upgrade.

I didn't see a way to set the default view to Full, on the command line.

This was using setup_x66-64.exe version 2.897, with only the --no-admin option, running in Windows 10.